# How to detect contours surrounding a shape extracted through template matching in opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

## Data description

- Dataset contains forms taken as pictures (so data quality varies greatly)
- All forms follow the same template

Here's a cropped image sample from the template to get an idea.

[image: Image sample]

## Aim

- Aim is to manage to detect the presence of the black arrow around
  either of the three vehicles.
- The arrow can be anywhere around a vehicle and can even be partly inside the vehicle

## What has been tried

- Preprocessing : basically follows [this answer](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/04/21/building-pokedex-python-finding-game-boy-screen-step-4-6/)
- Information extraction : Used opencv's [multi scale template matching](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/) to extract the vehicles, then used [contour approximations](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/04/21/building-pokedex-python-finding-game-boy-screen-step-4-6/) to extract contours, deleting the largest (which I suppose is the vehicle). Results were mediocre at best.

EDIT : Preprocessing and contour extraction is basically the following steps :

```
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    image = cv2.bilateralFilter(image, 11, 17, 17)
    image = cv2.Canny(image, 50, 200)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(image.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, 
              cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
```

Then I would start from the principle that the largest contours would be the vehicle and get the second largest, which I hope to be an arrow/whatever is drawn except the vehicle. Results are medioce because of two things :

- Grabbing second largest contour just leads to picking something within the vehicle or some random noise.
- Often my template matching is a bit inaccurate so I end up taking the horizontal line at the bottom of the form (the form's border) and it counts as contour, so I couldn't just say "any contour beyond the vehicle bounding box is fair game"

Comment: @Wadj Meskini, could you provide code example of what you tried and explain why the results are mediocre / what you expect?

Comment: @Waldi code snippet and explanation added as requested